# PostGIS SQL error in Java: no spatial operator found for st_contains

Tags: postgis, java

I'm quite new in PostGIS, and I'm trying to run an SQL query. I use this query to obtain a subset of segments from table roads in a group of polygons, then put the result in a separate table.

There are 3 tables:

- Table poly: a set of polygons
- Table roads: a set of road segments
- Table buffer: destination table

The query is like this:

```
WITH result AS 
(
  SELECT r.geom
  FROM roads r JOIN 
      (SELECT ST_UNION(geom) area 
      FROM poly) p
      ON (ST_CONTAINS(p.area, r.geom))
 )
INSERT INTO buffer
SELECT geom FROM result
;
```

When I run the query from pgAdmin 4, I can get the result exactly what I want.
However, when I run it from Java, I always get errors:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no spatial operator found for 'st_contains': opfamily 16513 type 16400
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279)
```

I created a Java ANT project in NetBeans 12. I installed the most recent Java, JDBC, Postgresql and PostGIS.
If I execute the common SQL queries **without** using any spatial function, no problems at all.
Below is my script to run the query.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gisdb", "user","password");
st = conn.createStatement();
qry= "WITH result AS ( "+
     "SELECT r.geom "+
     "FROM roads r JOIN "+
     "  (SELECT ST_UNION(geom) area FROM poly) p "+
     "ON (ST_CONTAINS(p.area, r.geom))) "+
     "INSERT INTO buffer "+
     "SELECT geom FROM buffer";
st.executeUpdate(qry);
```

Are there any settings that I missed? I have tried changing JOIN statement, using CTE but no luck. The error remains the same. I never have problems with Oracle or MySQL when calling complex queries with functions from Java.

edit:
I tried to change the username to **postgres** and the query can run successfully from Java. It seems that my username "user1" cannot access the ST function in public schema. Since I don't want to use administrator username in Java, which privileges should I grant to "user1"?

I tried both grants below with no luck:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS
IN SCHEMA public
TO user1;

GRANT USAGE 
ON SCHEMA PUBLIC
TO user1;
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify, in English, what you are attempting to accomplish with this query. Best practice is to use a JOIN, and if you really need a unary union, to use a CTE.

Comment: I use this query to obtain a subset of segments from table roads in a group of polygons, then put the result in a separate table. 

Like I said in the question, **the query runs without problem in pgAdmin4**, and I got the result as I want.

However, I cannot run the query if I put it in Java. 
I always encounter the error: "no spatial operator found"

Therefore, the problem is likely not about the SQL syntax.

Comment: Edit the question to add details, please. It doesn't really matter if pgAdmin accepts the query if you want Java to execute it, and it doesn't. Many programming languages apply strict SQL conformance rules, to prevent security failures in the SQL engine from compromising the server. You should try writing a conformant query (using CTE and a JOIN). In the meantime, an indication of the complexity of the polygons, and a diagram showing how you expect features which straddle the boundary to behave.

Comment: it sounds like this [bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4739), which occurs if the schema where Postgis is installed is not in the user search path.